# ::after content changes to weird characters when compiling less file to css

Tags: css, less

I have this **less file** that contains this line `&::after{content: '▼';}` but when compiled to **css** using **less compiler (lessc)** I get the following result `&::after{content: 'Ôû╝';}` in the css file.

On the website, the weird characters are displayed instead of the arrow down.

How can I make this content unchanged even though compilation process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need to replace this with is:

```
content: '\25BC';
```

Not all servers will recognize the actual character - but the code will be recognized every time.

If you want to simply use the character “▼” directly – you just need to save and open your file using the same, agreed on encoding. Otherwise you get the garbled symbol. The best encoding to use is UTF-8.

You can do this in your HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```